# Getting the output of a shell command in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, shell, command-line, terminal, jupyter-notebook

If I have a python file with the below script:

```
import pandas as pd

def csv():

    r = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,6],[1,3,4,5]])
    return r

csv()
```

How can I use a shell command in Jupyter Notebook to get the output of this script which is a pandas DataFrame. Or How do I modify the python script to do so but sill use a shell command in Jupyter (For some reason I need a shell command rather than just importing the function from the python file and executing it)

What I tried so far is the following but did not work ( want the Pandas DataFrame as output)

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['python','MyPythonFile.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or

```
result = ! python MyPythonFile.py
```

Comment: You want `=!` <- note there's no space between the two symbols

Comment: The first Python script doesn't produce any output. It needs to call `print()` somewhere, e.g. `print(csv())`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget What is `=!` supposed to mean?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Didn't make any difference.

Comment: @Barmar Print doesn't return the pandas DataFrame object. The "!" is a jupyter specific magic to run shell commands inside it.

Comment: Calling `csv()` doesn't produce any output. You could change `return r` to `print(r)`.

Comment: `result = !command` should totally be working, regardless of spaces. 
What's your error message? If you don't get an error, double-check the result of the shell command.

Comment: I have NO idea why his has not more votes! my gosh, thanks for asking this question!

Answer (score 3):

Access the "stdout" argument of the result:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['python','MyPythonFile.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stdout)
```

Edit: you cannot pass a DataFrame through unix stdout. DataFrame is a Python object, that has no meaning to the operating system. Use imports to execute your code inside of another python script, or export the generated objects through pickle or similar. What you are trying to accomplish is impossible if you do not completely change your strategy.

Comment: Didn't return the DataFrame object.

Comment: @AlirezaRanjbar That's because the first script doesn't produce any output, as I pointed out in comments.

Comment: @Barmar using print() doesn't give the actual pandas DataFrame object, and my question is mainly about that.

Comment: @AlirezaRanjbar You can't pass objects themselves through a pipe, only strings.

Comment: (the one who made the answer above) this was brilliant!  thanks!